# What is the difference between dual single-ended op amp and fully differential opamp?

Tags: operational-amplifier

Are they same things? Don't they both output bipolar/mirrored outputs?
Im confused with the terminology here.

What is the difference between dual single-ended op amp and a fully differential opamp?

Comment: Please provide any link that you can find to either parts bearing that description.

Comment: [Possibly related question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/371331/differential-amplifier-and-op-amp)

Answer (score 3):

A dual single-ended op amp is just two single-ended op amps mounted in the same package.  They can be used independently of each other.

A differential op amp is one op amp with two outputs,